# Accessing the Standard object Account in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

Intending to access the records of the standard object Account in Saleforce through the following code in VisualForce.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    Hello {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName} !
<p>
   1---- You are viewing the Account of - {!account.name}
</p>
<p>
   2---- Name Label in Account Object : {!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label} !
</p>
<p>
   3---- Datatype of Name in Account Object : {!$ObjectType.Account.Fields['Name'].Type} !
</p>

</apex:page>
```

1. It is not giving any value , while it should give the name of the object.
2. Its giving some output ie.( Account Name ) , which is pretty much not clear how
3. Its also giving some output ie. (Name) , not very clear.

Now, how to access the records in the object Account and print them .
Kindly Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bring an `Account` record into the current context, you must `add a query parameter to the page URL that specifies the ID of the record`. Get the Account Id and pass it to the Page.

for example:

```
https://na.salesforce.com/001D000000IRt53
https://Salesforce_instance/apex/PageName?id=001D000000IRt53
```

[Check here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm)

**Edit** : If you want display all the records of Account Object

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
  <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" id="list">
     <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
     --Other columns--
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Here it will display `all the Account Records` and no need to send ID.

Hope it helps you

Comment: how and where to add this query Parameter .

Comment: In the URL you need to pass the Account ID..For ex : https://Salesforce_instance/001D000000IRt53.

Comment: The above code is not returing any values from the Account Object . Do i need to add a query Parameter in the Above VisualForce Code.

Comment: https://ap1.salesforce.com/0019000000yMRZH - This is one of my Account Entry , But i am still not clear that where to add and how to do that in my visualforce Page URL i.e. - https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Object_Try?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1/0019000000yMRZH

Comment: I got it @NullReferenceException that the later half id needs to be appended at the URL of the Page .. But what if i need to get the entire list of the Account present.

Comment: See my Edit Answer...that will display all the Account List